# Vscode keeps adding spaces (indents) to my lines

Tags: visual-studio-code

When every i press enter key on the end of a line, vscode is adding spaces to this new line.

I have tried every setting i can think of to disable anything that has to do with indenting, but it doesn't help.

Here is a demo:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check your version any type of update coming or not.

If your version is new then first check if you have installed any extension or intellisis.
If you have installed any new extensions then delete and reinstall them. Sometimes new extensions will create problems. If that is not working then try to uninstall VS code and then reinstall.

Comment: Thanks! disabling extentions, and then enabling them again fixed it for me.